# novnc ready: native websockets, canvas rendering

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vps, linode, novnc

When I try to install windows on my VPS, I can't access Glish---the graphic website console(but browser console works).

When I open the Glish console, it prompted:

> novnc ready: native websockets, canvas rendering

How can I solve this?..

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got the answer...
It just simply because the browser(opera) didn't support the flash which used by Glish Graphical Website Console. Use safari, problem simply solved...